# Get View's index from UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I have added 2 views in `stackview` with different size. Now When I click on plus button of any view, I just wanted to add a view right below that.

I am getting view by:

```
let index = superView.subviews.index(of: view)
```

and then I am doing:

```
superView.insertArrangedSubview(newView, index + 1)
```

but actually it is adding new view at different position.

So If I try to get index by `.subview.index` then it always returns last index

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `arrangedSubviews` and `subviews` arrays don't have to be the same (because a stack view can have a subview that is not “arranged”). Even if they have the same elements, they don't have to be in the same order.

So:

```
if let index = stackView.arrangedSubviews.firstIndex(of: view) {
    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(newView, at: index + 1)
}
```

Comment: **firstIndex(of:)** is for xcode 10 , try your **index(of**